Remotely change GRUB's boot OS option, from Windows to Linux
I have a BIOS PC (non UEFI) with two SSDs: Windows 10 and Ubuntu. GRUB and Linux are in the first SSD, and GRUB boots the same OS of the last boot. The machine has wake-on-lan enabled and sometimes I access it remotely (SSH, RDP, VNC, etc.).
If the last boot was Ubuntu, and I want start Windows, I can do it remotely: wake the machine up; SSH to Ubuntu; edit /etc/default/grub, set Windows as default (instead of saved OS); update-grub; reboot. Next GRUB's boot will be Windows.
But if the last used OS is Windows, GRUB will keep booting Windows.
Is there a way to acess Windows REMOTELY and set the computer to change the next boot to Linux, again? Once Linux boots, I can remotely ssh it and change GRUB options as needed.
If there was only one SSD, maybe I could use Windows' utilities FDISK and bootrec to mark the Linux partition (as long it was a primary partition) as bootable, and recreate the boot record overwriting GRUB. This option isn't viable with two disks.
I wonder if I created a small Linux boot partition in the first SSD, so I could use Windows' Fdisk to enable this partition as bootable and start Linux directly - but, again, I should overwrite the boot sector (replacing GRUB) each time I wanted to switch the default OS from Windows to Linux. From Linux, I would need to install GRUB again and setting Windows as default.
I could use a TFTP server where GRUB would get its config. I actually have a 24x7 Raspberry Pi in the network that could act as a TFTP server.
TL;DR: is there a solution which runs entirely on the remotely accessed machine, for REMOTELY changing GRUB's next boot, from Windows to Linux?

This solution adds a small (1 MiB) partition containing a FAT formatted volume to the second drive, where Windows resides. A new menu entry is added to GRUB, which when selected will boot Windows, if the file windows resides in the .boot folder on this FAT formatted volume. If windows file does not exist, when the new menu entry is selected, then GRUB will boot Ubuntu.
Note that Windows is installed in the first primary partition on the second drive. Instead of using individual System, Windows and Recovery volumes stored in separate partitions as described in the Microsoft website BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions, a single volume is used, which contains the content of the three individual volumes.
Operating Systems Used:
Windows 10 22H2 (19045.4780)
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Below are the steps used to implement this solution.

Create and initialize the new partition. Here, the second drive is assumed to using a MBR partition table, where the partition containing Windows is the first and only entry in the table. I entered the following in an Administrator Command Prompt window.
diskpart
list disk
select disk 1
list partition
select partition 1
shrink desired=1
create partition primary size=1
format fs=fat quick label=grubfat
assign letter=u
exit
mkdir u:\.boot
attrib +h u:\.boot
copy nul u:\.boot\windows

Below is the output. The new volume name is GRUBFAT and the new drive letter is U:. The .boot folder has the hidden attribute set.
C:\windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.3636

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: DESKTOP-F3VMONS

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          100 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          150 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            149 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> shrink desired=1

DiskPart successfully shrunk the volume by: 1024 KB

DISKPART> create partition primary size=1

DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> format fs=fat quick label=grubfat

  100 percent completed

DiskPart successfully formatted the volume.

DISKPART> assign letter=u

DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\Windows\System32>mkdir u:\.boot

C:\Windows\System32>attrib +h u:\.boot

C:\windows\system32>copy nul u:\.boot\windows
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\windows\system32>


Create the setboot utility for both Windows and Ubuntu. This utility has the following valid entries.



Command
Action




setboot
Shows either Windows or Ubuntu as the current default to boot.


setboot windows
Makes Windows the default to boot.


setboot ubuntu
Makes Ubuntu the default to boot.



The Windows version is shown below. This script should be placed in a file named setboot.cmd.
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set theFile=u:\.boot\windows
set p1=%1
if not defined p1 (
  if exist %theFile% (
    echo Windows
  ) else (
    echo Ubuntu
  )
  exit /b 0
)
set p1=%p1:"=%
set p2=%2
if not defined p2 (
  if /i "%p1%" == "windows" (
    if not exist %theFile% type nul >%theFile%
    exit /b 0
  )
  if /i "%p1%" == "ubuntu" (
    if exist %theFile% del %theFile%
    exit /b 0
  )
)
echo usage: setboot [windows ^| ubuntu]
exit /b 1

The Ubuntu version is shown below. This script should be placed in a file named setboot.
#!/usr/bin/bash
theFile=/media/grubfat/.boot/windows
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  if [[ -e $theFile ]]; then
    echo Windows
  else
    echo Ubuntu
  fi
  exit 0
fi
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
  if [[ ${1,,} == windows ]]; then
    if [[ ! -e $theFile ]]; then cat /dev/null >$theFile; fi
    exit 0
  fi
  if [[ ${1,,} == ubuntu ]]; then
    if [[ -e $theFile ]]; then rm $theFile; fi
    exit 0
  fi
fi
echo "usage: setboot [windows | ubuntu]"
exit 1

For this script to work properly, the following line will need to be added to the /etc/fstab file.
LABEL=GRUBFAT   /media/grubfat  vfat    gid=100,dmask=007,fmask=007,utf8    0   0


Add a new menu entry to GRUB. Below is a template for the menuentry to add to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file.
Note: You can omit the echo and sleep commands, if you wish.
menuentry 'Ubuntu or Windows 10' --class os $menuentry_id_option 'Ubuntu-or-Windows' {
    insmod part_msdos
    if [ -e (hd1,msdos2)/.boot/windows ]; then
      echo 'Booting Windows 10'
      sleep 2
#
#     Below should be a copy of the contents of the menuentry for Windows.
#
    else
      echo 'Booting Ubuntu'
      sleep 2
#
#     Below should be a copy of the contents of the menuentry for Ubuntu.
#
    fi
}


The menuentry contents for Windows and Ubuntu can be copied from the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. As a reference, the menuentry 'Ubuntu or Windows 10' I added to my /etc/grub.d/40_custom file is given below. Note: I have Ubuntu installed to BIOS boot from first drive, which is using a GUID partition table (GPT).
menuentry 'Ubuntu or Windows 10' --class os $menuentry_id_option 'Ubuntu-or-Windows' {
    insmod part_msdos
    if [ -e (hd1,msdos2)/.boot/windows ]; then
      echo 'Booting Windows 10'
      sleep 2
#
#     Below should be a copy of the contents of the menuentry for Windows.
#
      savedefault
      insmod part_msdos
      insmod ntfs
      set root='hd1,msdos1'
      if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  A436DDD636DDA996
      else
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A436DDD636DDA996
      fi
      parttool ${root} hidden-
#     drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
      chainloader +1
    else
      echo 'Booting Ubuntu'
      sleep 2
#
#     Below should be a copy of the contents of the menuentry for Ubuntu.
#
      recordfail
      savedefault
      load_video
      gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
      insmod gzio
      if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
      insmod part_gpt
      insmod ext2
      set root='hd0,gpt2'
      if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  c171bdaf-cef0-4b42-adbf-04118f6c9917
      else
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c171bdaf-cef0-4b42-adbf-04118f6c9917
      fi
      linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=c171bdaf-cef0-4b42-adbf-04118f6c9917 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
      initrd    /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
    fi
}




Below is image of the new GRUB menu.

Post a comment if you have any questions. New users can also try posting a new question with a reference to this answer.

What a clever and sophisticated solution, yet relatively simple! Personally, I could already start looking for a solution based solely on the information that GRUB is capable of defining boot options by following a script, which reads a file on disk (or checks the existence of a file). However, your answer is even more detailed, including a detailed explanation of how to implement the script, as well as the programs that change the flag on disk.

I still have one question: is it really necessary for the flag file to be on a new FAT partition created exclusively for it? Couldn't GRUB look for the boot definition directly in a file on the Windows NTFS volume? Considering that both Windows and Linux could write to this volume whenever it was necessary to adjust the flag-file for booting the other OS.

I suppose you could use the Windows NTFS volume. Note that there are may websites which warn about have Linux write to the Windows NTFS volume. For example, this one and this one.

The main reason for writing the flag file in NTFS partition is that the disk is MBR disk in a legacy-bios machine, so, the disk has 3 primary + 1 extended partitions limit. I wouldn't worry with Linux writing to a NTFS partition, as long as the NTFS volumes has been properly unmounted by Windows. I remark that the two discussions that you linked are somewhat old (one has 10 years, other has 5 years). I think there's an urban legend about Linux messing with NTFS volumes, a kind of Microsoft-feeded FUD. As in my experience, I never had a glitch with Linux writing in NTFS volumes.

To be clear about the partitions limit: in a MBR disk/BIOS machine, Windows 10 uses 3 primary partitions: one system partition (somewhat analogous to UEFI boot partition), one Windows partition, and one recovery partition. There could be a fourth primary partition instead of an extended one. I don't "like" shred my disks in many partitions, but I acknowledge that this is a remnant from the HDDs' days. Now we're talking about a 120GB Kingston SSD, so, despite my ancient concerns, there is no problem in creating the fourth primary partition, or even the extended one with a partition inside it.

Your question did not specify how you partitioned your drives. I used a GUID Partition Table (GPT) for the first drive where Ubuntu is installed and MBR partition table on the second drive where Windows is installed. My answer is based on how I partitioned. Since you partitioning is different, you may want to modify my answer to fit your needs.

While the MBR partition table is limited to 4 partitions, the actual number of volumes allowed can exceed 4. Only the system volume has to be stored in a primary partition. The windows and recovery volumes can be stored in either a primary partition or a logical drive (residing in the extended partition). However, in my answer, I only used 1 volume stored in a single primary partition for Windows instead of the 3 primary partitions you used.

Please, my two last comments weren't a demeanor to your answer (which is perfect and fits to many more cases than my single initial question). I didn't say that the disks were MBR because, untill a few minutes ago, I didn't know that, most of times, a BIOS machine can boot GPT disks (in other words, when I said that was a BIOS machine, I tought - wrongly - that everyone could know that the disks were MBR). I don't remember if was Win10 who formated the disk as MBR (because of BIOS), or if the disk already was MBR when I installed Win10.

Historically MS OSses have quirks about partitions' nature, primary partitions, extended, etc., and, as I have a MBR disk, I tought that I didn't have other options to partititioning it: I tought that Windows really need all the three primary partitions that it grabbed when was installed. I didn't know that Windows and recovery could be in volumes in the extended partition. But, at last, and since it is a SSD, the fourth MBR primary partition, formatted as FAT, is the simpler way to go, indeed.
